# What is the number next to the opened file name in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

In visual studio, what does the number next to the file name represent? It is the exact same file.

Here is an example:
[image: 1]]

It started doing this a few weeks ago and I can't find any information about this. Is there  a way to deactivate this feature?

Comment: alt + [number] to switch between tabs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For me it's the window number instance whenever I open a new window for that file.

Comment: What's the use of having multiple window instances if it's the same file?

Comment: To have large files side by side in separate window tabs showing different functions that are in the same file is one reason that comes to mind.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a known VS bug reported here: [VS 15.9 Duplicate loads open files on solution reload](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/383817/vs-159-duplicate-loads-open-files-on-solution-relo.html).