# what is the meaning of ":" in VS2017 source code label title

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image]

I don't know, what does the `:1` `:2` mean, could any one tell me?

Comment: This seems to have started happening for me very recently, I'm not sure why. I think it just distinguishes 2 Windows on the same file. Not sure how it happens - trying to open the same file twice used to send you to the one that was already open. I'm only seeing this happen when I open a solution.

Comment: A simple way to get it is Window > New Window.  Now you have two text editor windows that refer to the same file.  And the :1 and :2 to distinguish them.  Note that you may have too many open files to see all of their tabs, click on the little down-arrow at the right of the tab well to see a list.  You'd probably want to close one of the editor windows to avoid confusion.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597543/what-is-the-number-next-to-the-opened-file-name-in-visual-studio