# Why Visual Studio 2017 appends numbers right to open files

Tags: visual-studio

Why Visual Studio adds this numbers?
Is some sort setting or a bug?

[image]

Comment: Hi @spiderman77, I found a similar question with a (not so satisfying) answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999070/visual-studio-2013-what-do-the-number-suffixes-in-the-file-tabs-mean

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639233/84507